# immutable borrow lifetime in 'match'

Tags: rust

The rust code is below:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::from([0, 1, 2]);

    for i in 0..5 {
        match v.get(i) {
            Some(x) => {
                let u: usize = *x;
                v[*x] = v[*x] + 1; // Not OK???
                v[u] = v[*x] + 1; // OK
            }
            None => v.push(i + 1),
        }
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

And I got a compile error.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src\main.rs:9:17
  |
6 |         match v.get(i) {
  |               - immutable borrow occurs here
...
9 |                 v[*x] = v[*x] + 1; // Not OK???
  |                 ^ -- immutable borrow later used here
  |                 |
  |                 mutable borrow occurs here
```

The `*x` and `u` hold the same value. But the compiler prevent me to use a deref value as a usize index to access the position in vector.
Could someone tell me the difference between `v[*x] = v[*x] + 1` and  `v[u] = v[*x] + 1` ?

Comment: It's a bit weired but makes sense if you consider that `x` borrows `v`, while `u[v] =` must do a mutable borrow. It has to do with the exact order the borrows are released

Comment: If you change the match pattern to `Some(&x)` and use `x` instead of `*x` it will also work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to answer this is to consider the order in which expressions get evaluated.  In Rust, almost all expressions are evaluated left-to-right.  However, assignment is evaluated right-to-left.  In your code, we have this basic form:

```
a[b] = c + d
```

Since assignment happens right-to-left, the right side is evaluated before the left side.  Within each side, evaluation is left-to-right, so the overall order of evaluation here is:

1. `c`
2. `d`
3. `c + d`
4. `a`
5. `b`
6. `a[b]`
7. The assignment is performed.

Note that optimizations can cause some reordering at the assembly level, but the above order is what is applied when performing semantic checks during compilation.

In your case, note that `x` borrows immutably from `v`.  This is not an issue for calculation of the assigned value, because the entire right side of the assignment is evaluated before the left side.

Consider `v[u] = v[*x] + 1`.  When `v` is evaluated, a mutable reference to it is taken.  After `v` is evaluated, `u` is, but this is fine because `u` does not borrow from anything.

Now consider `v[*x] = v[*x] + 1`.  After `v` is evaluated, `*x` is evaluated.  But `x` borrows from `v`, and we've already evaluated (taken a mutable reference to) `v`!  This is a violation of Rust's [aliasing rule](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/borrow/alias.html), and so you get an error.

The `v[u]` approach is the workaround to this situation, because this forces evaluation of `*x` before a mutable reference to `v` is taken.

Comment: Is the violation happened in step `6` of your evaluation order decomposisition?
if yes,  why no voilation happend in the evalution for `v[*x]` of right side of assignment ?

Comment: @zhaokaixie `v[*x]` does not need mutable access to `v` unless you try to assign to it. So it needs mutable access for the left hand side of the assignment, but not the right hand side.

Comment: @zhaokaixie The violation happens at step 5 when the immutable borrow against `v` is evaluated at the same time there is an outstanding mutable borrow.

Comment: @cdhowie actually the violation happens at step 4 when you try to take a mutable borrow of `v` while there is still a live immutable borrow through `x`. Note for example that the error also occurs in the `v[u] = …` case if we use `x` later: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f1812a3f35ade46ea252067325a3eafd) even though in my example step 5 doesn't reference `v` at all.